# Reverse translation

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I have a problem. 
My multilingual site have 'Italian' as default language and I have a problem with the taxonomy name translation.

In views when I add taxonomy name field this is always displayed in Italian ad never translated so I think to sobstitute the name field to a php field like

```
<?php print t($row->name); ?>
```

but $row->name is italian and the t() function assume this string in english and translate it when the site is 'IT'

I tryed to use taxonomy context but drupal double the entry
[image]

How can I have in my damn view a field with the right taxonomy name?
Can I tell drupal 'translate from IT to EN when the site is English'?

Comment: Good luck with that. I gave up long time ago and now I write everything in English. Even if I never plan to display English version. Additional bonus - I don't need to change code of my modules when marketing decides to change texts.

Comment: I can't resetup all the site language and trnslated string only for ONE block in the site T_T

Why the context exist if they don't work?

Comment: I know, that's why I didn't post this as an *answer*.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it for an array of untranslated terms:

```
foreach ($terms as $term => $str) {
  $translation = db_query("SELECT t.translation FROM {locales_source} s LEFT JOIN {locales_target} t ON s.lid = t.lid AND t.language = 'en' WHERE s.source = :source", array(':source' => $str))->fetchAll();
  $terms[$term] = $translation[1]->translation;
}
```